# Do skins exterior quality reduce from use?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Say I had a Factory New weapon skin, if I used the skin in game would the quality gradually reduce and become Minimal Wear or less?

Will it go down over time even if I don't use it?

Comment: find a better translator

Comment: Your original question was extremely hard to understand.  Can you try adding a few more details about what you're looking for?  Just in case the edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they do not wear out over time.

The skins are found at their different wear levels starting at Factory New and going down (minimal wear, battle worn etc are examples of other wear levels). But using them does not cause them to degrade over time.